# Kotlin Back4app ParseUser authentication

Tags: kotlin, authentication, back4app

I have 2 simple questions, although it seems simple to me but I couldn't find any helpful materials out there! The question is:

1. How can I login with email and password instead of username and password with Back4app ParseUser using kotlin?
2. How do I sign up a user with google account with Back4app ParseUser using kotlin?

is it because it does not support any of those features?

I tried adding everything and nothing seems to be workkng

Answer (score 0):

1. Logging in by email instead of login works if the user has passed email verification. the user simply writes an email instead of a username and password and logs in.
2. Logging in via Google and other services is not implemented in the android sdk. But these methods are specified on the platform, so I think it needs to be implemented through cloud code. Maybe I'm wrong or you've found the answer to this question, then let me know, I'm also solving this issue.